# SOA with dynamic forms

Tags: web-services, front-end, middleware, forms

When building a Service Oriented Architecture (because the services will be used by automated systems or other consumers), how can I go about creating a simple, dynamic form-based web frontend for said services.

As an example: A service needs 10 input values and returns a set of matching elements. To get to the values of those 10 inputs, for human end-users a wizard-like form is the best approach. This form is highly dynamic, meaning selecting *10,5* in one select-field will make the list of available values in the next dropdown smaller.

This is domain-specific knowledge that the frontend should not/can not have.

But: Moving this knowledge to the services seems to also be wrong because it's about HOW the data is displayed, not WHAT data is displayed.

I thought about creating a middleware but that just splits up the domain knowledge and I always have to ask myself "is this for the service or the middleware?"

Are there well-tested approaches on how to create a highly dynamic frontend (specifically forms) and "marry" that with a service architecture that shouldn't know about how its data is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

> When building a Service Oriented Architecture (because the services will be used by automated systems or other consumers), how can I go about creating a simple, dynamic form-based web frontend for said services.

Why would you want to do so?

What your clients need is a *proxy* [class] that enables them to programatically call your Service.

Such a proxy can be generated from the WSDL (Web Service Definition Language) for the Service, which you should be able to retrieve.  This is how tools like Visual Studio create test harnesses for WebServices.

> This is domain-specific knowledge that the frontend should not/can not have.

If the client has *no* knowledge of a Service's contract or interface, then it cannot use that Service!

You need to get hold of the Service's WSDL and interpret that.